# TCL script is giving error when trying to commit file using SVN command

Tags: svn, scripting, tcl

I am trying to commit a file in svn through a tcl script. I am running following command in tcl script

```
catch {exec svn commit -m'SDR' 'C:\abc\def\a.txt'} results
```

This is returning following error

```
svn: E020024: Error resolving case of 'C:\abc\def\a.txt'
```

I have tried everything that I can. Posting here with the hope of getting it solve. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `'` characters mean nothing at all to Tcl, unlike with the shell you're more used to using. Fortunately, that's often best addressed by just putting those values — without the `'` characters — in Tcl variables and just using them. Formally, Tcl uses `{`…`}` where shells use `'`…`'`, but anything that makes the right string will do in practice.

Also, Tcl's very keen on converting `\` to `/` in filenames; we need to take a little care there too because we're handing the filename off to a subprocess (and `file nativename` is *exactly* the care we need).

```
# I'm going to factor these two out into variables; that sort of thing that makes sense
set message "SDR"
set file [file join C:/ abc def a.txt]

catch {exec svn commit -m $message [file nativename $file]} results
```

Of course, in practice many applications have a notion of a working area that they do their file operations within. It might be the current working directory, it might be somewhere else (it *really* depends on the app), but it's often best to put the name of it in a variable of its own. Then you can use names within that scope much more easily:

```
set workingArea [file join C:/ abc]

set message "SDR"
set file [file join $workingArea def/a.txt]

catch {exec svn commit -m $message [file nativename $file]} results
```

And I'd *actually* wrap some of that up in a procedure if it was my own code (this uses `lmap`, which was introduced in Tcl 8.6):

```
proc svnCommit {message args} {
    global workingArea
    set code [catch {
        exec svn commit -m $message {*}[lmap f $args {
            file nativename [file join $workingArea $f]
        }]
    } results]
    return [list $code $results]
}

lassign [svnCommit "SDR" def/a.txt] code results
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the file join command solves the issue on my machine:

```
catch {exec svn commit -m'SDR' [file join C:\\ abc def a.txt]} results
```

Comment: You probably want to completely remove the `'` characters; they don't mean anything at all when programming in Tcl.